# Python Django Update User and UserProfile in a same form

Tags: python, django

I am starting to learn python and `django` framework and messing around with `UserChangeForm` imported from `django.contrib.auth.forms` and now attempting to update the User info and User profile at the same time this is by combining the two fields.

Here is my `forms.py`

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
```

And here is my `view.py`

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', args)
```

Here is my `model.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

I was wondering if i can add the fields on my `EditProfileForm` class if that is possible? any suggestion would be great!

```
 fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password','city','description')
```

Comment: Which model are those fields stored in? I assume they're not stored in the User model, but in some Profile model (or some other name) with a one-to-one relationship to user?

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes its stored in my Profile Models, can fields be combined?

Comment: How do you mean "combined"? But if the form as here relates to 2 different models, you can't do it with a modelForm. Just inherit from `django.forms.Form`, and then in your view you'll need to alter and save objects from both of these models.

Comment: What i mean combine is allow the user to edit User and UserProfile in a single template (edit_profile), inheriting the `django.forms.form` might be complicated for me :(  but i will try.

Comment: It's not that complicated - you just need to construct two separate objects in the view from the appropriate form responses. Good luck with it, and feel free to update your question (or start a new one) if you have problems.